# Getting "Reference Assemblies" path in MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm updating a build to be compatible with .NET 4.5, and one of the changes I need to make is [updating how I call ilmerge](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2012/02/29/What-you-should-know-about-running-ILMerge-on-Net-45-Beta-assemblies-targeting-Net-40.aspx).

From the link above, this basically means changing:

```
/targetplatform:"v4,C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
```

to:

```
/targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"
```

In my MSBuild AfterBuild target I was generating the former using `$(MSBuildToolsPath)`, like this:

```
/targetplatform:v4,$(MSBuildToolsPath)
```

What's the best way to translate this into the required `/targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"` path so that it works on x64, x86 or any unusual places it can wind up installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the GetReferenceAssemblyPaths task within your target. Have it save the output to a item name or property and replace the $(msbuildtoolsPath) with this new property. You can also add a condition check to determine what you need to pass to ILMerge.

```
<GetReferenceAssemblyPaths BypassFrameworkInstallChecks="False" TargetFrameworkMoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
    <Output TaskParameter="FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="path" />
</GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>
```

Comment: Thanks! One gotcha I found was that `ItemName="path"` meant I needed to use `@(path)` syntax to reference the value, or change `ItemName` to `PropertyName` to use `$(path)`. The other gotcha is that the path contained a trailing path delimiter ` \ ` which caused trouble executing the command, so I had to use `$(path).` (trailing '.') to get the command to use the correct path.

Comment: I am glad you were able to get around the ItemName problem and use the PropertyName="path" instead. It makes more sense to do it this way in your case since you only have one value. I will update the solution to make it easier for anybody else that may use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a registry key that contains the information (or important elements of the information you need) then I'd use the `$(Registry:<key name>[@<value name>])` syntax to obtain it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/05/04/new-registry-syntax-in-msbuild-v3-5.aspx